# Knitr and kable not finding data frame

Tags: r, knitr

I am attempting to show a simple table in knitr on a word document.  I have the following code:

```
library(knitr)
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
tab<-data.frame(a,b)
```

In the console this runs correctly

```
knitr::kable(tab)
```

However when put into a markdown documents called 'medinventory' the code does not run properly and returns the following error:

`````
````{r echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
knitr::kable(tab)
````  

processing file: medinventory.Rmd
|......................                                           |  33%
ordinary text without R code

|...........................................                      |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 2
$ echo   : logi FALSE
$ results: chr "asis"


Quitting from lines 17-18 (medinventory.Rmd) 
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'tab' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> <Anonymous> -> colnames ->                              
is.data.frame
Execution halted
`````

So the data frame is in the globalEnvr but not recognized by markdown?  I would appreciate any links to related questions as well as an answer.

Comment: Why don't you add the data frame creation to the markdown code? Not only this should work but it actually makes the Rmarkdown reproducible if you need to generate the output again.

Comment: What Molx said. Any R object that you want to use in a knitr code chunk needs to be created in a code chunk.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the tip @Molx.  Why is this not the case with mtcars?

Comment: `mtcars` is one of the datasets available in the `datasets` package which is loaded with base R. Others are `iris` and `airquality`, for example. You can see the full list using `library(help = "datasets")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Molx for the answer, and @D.Mercer for the comments.  Everything in the markdown code.

````
```{r echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
library(knitr)
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
tab<-data.frame(a,b)
knitr::kable(tab)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. An object created in previous code chunk can be accessed by next one. The problem you had because you probably forgot to define `tab` object before or previous code did not run as opposed to what @D.Mercer is suggesting.

Comment: Please Use Comment For this type of suggestion and if you don't have enough point then don't do this. If you are adding answer please give proper description and reference example. Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)